# Rename file using python and returns its value

Tags: python

I wanted to rename multiple files and return its value. Is there any way other than os.rename(src,dst), because this method does not return renamed file name.

Comment: you already know what is the name of the `renamed` file :). Also, use `shutil` rather than `os` module

Comment: Tagging both `python-3.x` and `python-2.7` contributes no information to your question.

Comment: I am new to this website, Thanks for your suggestion @khelwood.

Answer (score 0):

You know what the new name will be, since you pass it to `os.rename`. If you really need it as a return value, you could just wrap `os.return` with your own function:

```
def renameFile(src, dst):
    os.rename(src, dst)
    return dst
```